# Dot in a selected radiobutton with bg, fg specified disappears

Tags: python, tkinter

Beginner question: I'm trying to change the colour of my GUI, particularly the radiobuttons. I need inverted colours, so black background, white text.

```
self.radiobuttonVariable = Tkinter.IntVar()
radiobutton1 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text=u'E', variable = self.radiobuttonVariable, 
                                       bg='black', fg='white' activebackground='black', activeforeground='white', 
                                       value = 1, command = self.RadioSelect)
radiobutton1.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='ES')
```

This looks just fine, but when I press the button, it's the dot is there only as long I'm pressing it, disappears as soon as I let it go. The variable doesn't change, it stays on the right value, just that the dot disappears. No issue whatsoever when I remove the colour-management options. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `self.RadioSelect` do?

Comment: irrelevant, at this moment just prints the value.

Comment: Show a working example, so that we can run it and test if it's a platform specific problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, specifying the foreground (presumably for the text) *also* sets the selected "dot color".  You can set the `selectcolor` attribute of the element to color the "background" of the radiobutton so that you can see the white dot.

For example, `selectcolor='red'` in Windows:

[image: win-red]

Be aware that the [manpage](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/radiobutton.htm#M9) indicates that coloring *all* radio buttons with `selectcolor` (instead of only the selected button) may be Windows-only:

> Under Windows, this color is used as the background for the indicator regardless of the select state.

That being said, I got the same effect in linux under Python 2.7 and 3.3:

[image: linux-red]

I just used red to distinguish the part of the widget that `selectcolor` affected, you'd probably want `selectcolor='black'` or something a bit lighter to show the depression `selectcolor='#222222'` (below):

[image: win-dark]

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works. Now that I think of it, I should've just studied the documentation. Is there a way to alter default colour values for all widgets of particular type, so that I don't have to add options to every widget in my GUI?

Comment: @zephi If you keep track of your widgets somehow (append their references to in a list maybe), you can iterate through them and set attributes that they have in common (e.g. `fg`, `bg`), but things like `selectcolor` will need to be set in the respective widgets, since not all widgets have that attribute.

Comment: That's a neat idea for more complex user interfaces, might just create one list per widget type to eliminate unknown option error. Thanks a lot!